# Mixing contravariant and covariant types in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, scala-java-interop, existential-type

I am trying to build a framework with a hierarchy of `Context`s (that hold immutable data) and `Module`s that create actors work with the data.  Subclasses on `Context` include more data (e.g., a `RemoteContext` would have information about how to communicate with remote hosts).  There are also `Factory` objects to make the relevant objects, which is part of the data in the `Context`.

I can define the hierarchy with sub-classes, and that works fine.  Once everything is defined, a `Mediator` object initializes each `Module` by passing the context.

The code below shows that basic structure.

```
import java.{ util => ju}

trait Factory
trait Context[F <: Factory]

trait SomeContext[F <: Factory] extends Context[F]

trait MediatorModule[C <: Context[_ <: Factory]] {
    def loadModule(c: C)
}

trait Mediator[C <: Context[Factory]] {
    val context: C
    def getModules: ju.List[MediatorModule[_ >: C]]
    def run() = getModules.forEach(_.loadModule(context))
}

trait OtherFact extends Factory
trait OtherContext extends SomeContext[OtherFact]

class SomeModule extends MediatorModule[SomeContext[Factory]] {
    def loadModule(c: SomeContext[Factory]): Unit = { }
}
class OtherModule extends MediatorModule[OtherContext] {
    def loadModule(c: OtherContext): Unit = { }
}

class OtherContextImpl extends OtherContext {

}

class OtherMediator extends Mediator[OtherContext] {
    val context: OtherContext = new OtherContextImpl
    def getModules: ju.List[MediatorModule[_ >: OtherContext]] =
        ju.Arrays.asList(new SomeModule,
                         new OtherModule)
}
```

(The code was originally written in Java, which is why it is using Java lists).

As written, this fails to compile:

```
Test.scala:78:26: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : SomeModule
[error]  required: MediatorModule[_ >: OtherContext]
[error] Note: SomeContext[Factory] <: Any (and SomeModule <: MediatorModule[SomeContext[Factory]]), but trait MediatorModule is invariant in type C.
[error] You may wish to define C as +C instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]         ju.Arrays.asList(new SomeModule,
[error]                          ^
[error] one error found
```

Following the compiler's suggestion by declaring `trait MediatorModule[+C <: Context[_ <: Factory]]` instead gives two errors:

```
Test.scala:52:20: covariant type C occurs in contravariant position in type C of value c
[error]     def loadModule(c: C)
[error]                    ^
[error] Test.scala:75:29: type arguments [OtherContext] do not conform to trait Mediator's type parameter bounds [C <: Context[Factory]]
[error] class OtherMediator extends Mediator[OtherContext] {
[error]                             ^
```

I can fix one with `trait Context[+F <: Factory]` but the co/contra variant error remains.

What can I do to fix that error?  Also, how does `+C` translate back to Java?

Comment: Without reading too much, usually you solve those with `def loadModule[C1 >: C](c: C1)` That way you flip the variance of **C**. I would suggest you to read first about variance, what does it mean and why it is important. Finally `+C` does not translate in anyway to **Java**, the JVM due type-erasure and other reasons does not manage variance. All that information is only used by the **Scala** compiler to avoid some bugs that are pretty easy to create on **Java**.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez While it's true that `+C` doesn't translate to Java, what you said afterwards is not true. Scala and Java both rely on the same JVM and have the same type-erasure mechanism. But the thing is, Java language only supports **call-site** or **use-site** variance, for example `Foo<? extends Integer> covariantFoo = new Foo<Integer>();`. Scala supports that (as `[_ <: Integer]`), but also supports **declaration-site** variance, e.g. `Foo[+C]`, saying that `Foo` is *always covariant in C*.

Comment: Your suggestion fixed the problem in the sample code.  Unfortunately, in the production code, the relevant parts are in Java, so I probably can't just make the corresponding changes.

Comment: @slouc Well yes, but again that only works for the compiler. The JVM in general does not support the concept of variance nor type parameters _(and in general terms that is good)_.

Comment: @TroyDaniels Mixing of variance in **Scala** + **Java** is difficult, because both manage them differently _(as slouc said)_. What is your objective? Integrate a Java component to a Scala project? or a Scala component on a Java project? Or slowly migrate from Java to Scala?

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez Yeah, I agree. I just wanted to point out that Java does allow variance, but only use-site, while Scala allows both use-site and declaration-site. This is a language difference. When we move from the compiler to the JVM, however, all that type information is heavily reduced in the same way for both languages.

Comment: @slouc Yeah, I am not sure if you misread or I write it bad _(since englih is not my native language)_. But, I (tried to) say that the one that did not had variance was the **JVM** not **Java** as a language _(but the latter does have a less powerful than **Scala**, which allows some bug, specially with `Arrays`)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The framework is written in Java, and will probably stay there, since other projects are also using it and are in Java.  I am currently trying to use it in Scala. In practice, some of the Modules and some Mediators are in Scala, and everything else is in Java

Comment: I am guessing that `<? extends Foo>` and `[_ <: Foo]` probably get translated to (almost) the same (simple?) byte code, but `[+Foo]` gets rather more to handle the variance.  Is that right?

Comment: @TroyDaniels again _variance_ does not exists at bytecode. _variance_ is a concept of the **type system** _(both Scala and Java have different ones)_ the JVM _(which is the **runtime system**, which both languages share)_ has `classes` not `types` you have _subclass_ relationships not _subtype_ relationship. My suggestion would be to write a wrapper over the framework on Scala, that wrapper probably would need to do some nasty things, `asInstanceOf` casts to make things compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make both `Context` and `SomeContext` covariant

```
trait Context[+F <: Factory]

trait SomeContext[+F <: Factory] extends Context[F]
```

Then the code compiles.